# Is locking the accessors of a property the correct/most efficient way to ensure thread safety in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, locking

I've created a class with two threads.  The threads share three Lists and several booleans.  One thread only ever reads these fields, the other thread reads and writes.

In order to make the booleans thread-safe, I created private properties for all of them, and locked their gets and sets (using an Object created specifically for locking).  For the lists I created properties with a locked get that returns an array via List.ToArray(), and then created locked Add methods for adding new items to the lists (using the lists themselves as locking objects).

My question is: creating all those properties added a whole lot of extra code to my class for what would, in a single-threaded class, just be private fields - so much so that it just seems sort of silly that there'd be so much overhead just to implement a second thread.  Is it necessary, or is there a better way of doing it?

(I've also just read another stackoverflow page that suggested that locking gets and sets isn't actually thread-safe, because they only lock the property and provide the caller with an unlocked reference to the field.  But this wouldn't be true of value types, would it?  And my List properties are returning arrays, not references to the list fields.)

EDIT: The class, as I said in my comment, is for establishing an ssh connection.  Most of the class is concerned with automating some stuff pertaining to the particular linux machines I'm connecting to.  The threaded part is just for sending commands to the shell and reading the output.

In the following example "Input" and "Output" refer to the locked properties that return arrays generated by the ToArray() method of the _input and _output Lists.

```
ShellStream.Open();
while(!StopThread)
{
     if (WaitForPrompt)
     {
          if (inputIndex > Input.Length)
          {
              ShellStream.WriteLine(Input[inputIndex]);
              inputIndex++;

              output = ShellStream.WaitForPrompt();
              AddOutput(output);
          }
      }
      else
      {
          if (inputIndex > Input.Length)
          {
              ShellStream.WriteLine(Input[inputIndex]);
              inputIndex++;
          }

          output = ShellStream.Read();

          if (out != null)
              AddOutput(output);
      }
}
ShellStream.Close();
```

Comment: I'd rather just lock the code *accessing* fields rather than locking fields themselves but it depends on what you need. Why not post some code?

Comment: Yes, this is hard to answer without more context. Are the threads internal to the class in question? What does client code do with the returned data?

Comment: If the values of the different properties relate to each other (and why would they be in the same class otherwise) then there's no point just making the properties individually threadsafe if the combination of actions upon them won't be; e.g. if you decide to do something on one of the lists due to the value of one of the booleans, then that boolean could have changed by the time you get the list.

Comment: Okay, I can see why context is useful in this instance.  So, the class is basically an ssh connection to a particular type of linux box which automated a bunch of the hoops that need to be jumped through in order to establish the connection.  The actual threaded part, though, is just sending commands to the ssh shell and reading the output.  I'll edit my original question to include some dummy code.

Comment: In this particular case, changing the value of the booleans between one loop and the next isn't going to make any difference that I care about to the output.  If I decide to start waiting for the prompt, I'll change that boolean before adding more commands to the input list.  I hadn't actually even thought about situations where the properties intimately relate to each other, simply because my code doesn't work that way.  It's something for me to keep in mind, though.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows the structure and usage of your code, it would not be possible to offer specific advice. It's true that `lock` around value types should be "safe" in terms of getting the value, but then so would declaring the fields `volatile`. A `lock` with a `bool` is usually used in conjunction with some _related_ resource that also needs conditional handling (i.e. based on the `bool`). There are just too few details here, and the code you added doesn't do anything to help understand the scenario.

Comment: My actual code is at the office, and I'm at home for the long weekend.  And the nature of this problem, I think, makes it really difficult for me to know just what code to post.

Comment: I guess I'm also confused about exactly what variables need to be locked.  I thought that marking something as volatile simply meant that it would not be stored in the CPU registers.  But I don't see how that makes it thread-safe if multiple threads can read and write to it without blocking.  Is a bool a special case?
I've seen some documents online that suggest it's okay with a bool because reads and writes to it are atomic - but MSDN says that reads and writes to reference types are also atomic, and yet the variables you definitely do have to lock are reference types.